# Rails: Reference an ActiveRecord model over a module with the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following standard Rails ActiveRecord `Foo` defined:

```rb
# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And I'm trying to call `Foo.find(..)` from within a hierarchy that contains a module also named `Foo`..

```rb
# lib/commands/bar.rb
module Commands
  module Bar
    module Create
      class Command
        def initialize(params)
          ...
          Foo.find(params[:foo_id]
          ...
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# lib/commands/foo.rb
module Commands
  module Foo
    module Create
      class Command
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby/Rails is finding `Commands::Foo` instead of my `Foo` Model and throwing `undefined method 'find' for Commands::Foo:Module`.. **how can I point at the correct ActiveModel implementation?**

The obvious answer is to rename `Commands::Foo..` to `Commands::Foos..` but I'm curious to know if there's another way  :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the clash then you should rename the modules. The existing structure is unwieldy and will present similar problems to all future maintainers.

The best solution that I find in your code is to ensure you call the appropriate module and method via its full path:

```
2.3.3 :007 > ::Commands::Foo::Create::Command.new
"Commands::Foo::Command reached"
 => #<Commands::Foo::Create::Command:0x007ffa1b05e2f0>
2.3.3 :008 > ::Commands::Bar::Create::Command.new
"Commands::Bar::Command reached"
 => #<Commands::Bar::Create::Command:0x007ffa1b04f110>
```

You shouldn't try to override or modify internal Rails calls, because then you've modified the framework to fit code, which leads to unpredictable side effects.

Comment: Thanks @Mark - I concatenated 2 `module`s to produce `::Commands::FooCreate::Command.new` so they don't clash with the ActiveModels  :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call`::Foo` in `Commands::Foo`, it should go with your `Foo` model

Comment: Can you explain why?